# PDFsharp Portfolio PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I have a program I wrote that merges PDF's to a single document using PDFsharp.  I now need to be able to specify these merged PDF's as portfolios.  I have tore through the documentation, and have not managed to find anything that looks to do this.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with 'portfolio', I'm not familiar with the usage of the term in combination with PDF.

Comment: Yeah, I wasnt either till it was just requested for me to change my output.  Essentially it is just a different default layout of the pdf.  When you open the document it has all of the pages scaled down, when you select one it goes to that page.  After the pdf has been combined however, individual pages no longer show up, they just show the first page of the combined file so I cant just write a simple bat.

Comment: I also have a problem similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284984/how-to-work-with-pdf-portfolio-in-itextsharp-how-to-identify-that-a-pdf-is-portf

Answer (score -1):

A pdf portfolio will also be having the extension as '.pdf' similar to a simple pdf but it's a collection of files. How you can specify that it is a pdf portfolio, i don't know. But you can check whether a pdf is a pdf portfolio or not using the **FreeSpire.pdf** **library** which is free/community version for Spire.pdf library. The following is the code using the library functions :

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
bool isPortfolio = pdf.IsPortfolio();
if(isPortfolio)
  Console.WriteLine("It is a pdf portfolio");
else
  Console.WriteLine("It is not a pdf portfolio");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Quote: "I now need to be able to specify these merged PDF's as portfolios". Can Spire set this flag? The snippet just shows how to read this flag.

Comment: There is a flag '/Collection' in Pdf portfolios is what I remeber from one of the stackOverflow threads, that can be used to identify that it is a pdf porfolio, but no idea how to set this.

Comment: Merging pdfs normally vs. Combining pdfs to a portfolio are two entirely different things pdf-wise. The latter is more related to adding the pdfs to a base pdf as attachments. Thus, merely *setting that **Collection** flag* won't make a merged pdf a portfolio of the source pdfs, just like clearing it won't make a portfolio a merged pdf.